# sIFR mouse wheel scrolling freeze in Firefox

Tags: firefox, sifr, mouseover, freeze

I have started using sIFR for a site at work, everything works very well except one thing.

When I'm scrolling down the webpage with the mouse wheel, it stops scrolling when the pointer is on the flash object. It seems like the flash object is stealing the the focus when the mouse is over it.

I have only been experiencing this problem in Firefox, Safari and IE7 didn't have this mouse wheel scrolling problem.

There must be a way to fix this... I've seen that on Vimeo, the mouse wheel scrolling is working even if the mouse is over a flash video. Example here: http://vimeo.com/3280159

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which OS are you using? Version of Flash? Version of sIFR?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP, flash player 10,0,22,87, and sIFR version 3, revision 436.

I've also tried changing the wmode of the flash object to transparent which actually solves the problem in Firefox, but the problems occurs in IE7.

Comment: Are you using some kind of CSS reset? And if so, which one?

Some CSS resets are too liberal and what they reset, causing all kinds of funky browser incompatibility issues (especially resets with the universal * selector)

Comment: Yes, I use Eric Meyer's CSS reset. But the universal selector is not used, but the object element is part of the reset. here is the a part of the CSS reset that mentions the object tag: (see next comment)

Comment: html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}

that the first part of the reset.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, which is not the best but it works...

i've added a condition in the sIFR replace function of the config file. I use jQuery to verify which browser is in use, **if it's IE: wmode=window, else if it's any browser, wmode=transparent**

```
var myfont = { src: '/sifrfont.swf' };
sIFR.activate(myfont );
sIFR.replace(myfont , {
  selector: 'h1',
  wmode: ($.browser.msie)?'window':'transparent',
  css: '.sIFR-root { color: #3e2616; font-size: 50; leading:0;letter-spacing: -2; display: inline;}'
});
```

I have tested this in Windows XP, with the following browsers: Firefox 3, Safari, IE6, IE7 and Google Chrome.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. It's not perfect but it's preferable to the answer suggesting to remove the scroll wheel event handler from sifr's AS3 source for reasons detailed in a comment to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using version 3 ran into the same issue on most browsers recently and the simplest solution we found was to comment out the line 201 in sIFR.as:
Mouse.addListener({onMouseWheel: function() { sIFR.instance.blur() }});
Then re-publish your .swf file.

Comment: this slution generally works but removing that method causes the sifr replaced headlines etc. to flicker in an ugly fashion when scrolling on Safari. I eventually used the solution above.